# Add bookmarks to Delicious and Google Bookmarks at the same time

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, bookmarks, delicious, google-bookmarks

I have used delicious.com (or back then, del.icio.us) to store my bookmarks for a long time now, and I love it.  I was looking through some of my Google services, and realized they have a bookmarking service that integrates with your Google searches (I thought they had a bookmarking service before, but it went away?  Maybe not).

I like delicious just fine - I'm not interested in leaving.  But I also like how my Google bookmarks are highlighted (and I'm guessing, brought to the top) in my search results so I can easily tell if I've bookmarked a site (kind of like the "promote up" feature).  I can't even count the number of times I search for a site only to find I've been there months or years ago.  If sites I've bookmarked in the past are highlighted in my search results, it makes it easier to pick which search result to go to.

My question is around bookmarking tools: **Is there a bookmarklet or Firefox addon that will let me save a bookmark to multiple services at the same time, in this case, Google and Delicious?**  Or maybe a service to sync my delicious bookmarks to Google bookmarks on a regular basis?  I have used the Delicious addon since the beginning - it would just be nice to add a bookmark to multiple services with 1 addon.

For that matter, it would be nice to add Evernote into the mix - click 1 button to save the page to Evernote, and bookmark the page in Google and delicious.

**EDIT on 7/30/2009 - Summary:**

A proposed solution is to use the [Delicious addon](http://delicious.com/help/quicktour/firefox) and the [GMarks addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2888) to keep the 2 services in sync.  I was not able to get the 2 addons to keep everything in sync, so it was also suggest to use the [Google Toolbar](http://toolbar.google.com) with the [Delicious addon](http://delicious.com/help/quicktour/firefox) to keep everything in sync.  I personally have reservations with letting Google know about every single site I visit, I believe this solution will work, so I am accepting it as the answer.

I still wish there was a solution that would let you post a bookmark/page to multiple services at the same time (delicious, google, evernote, digg, diigo, etc.).

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Delicious addon

https://   addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3615

This will install toolbar and sidebar. Toolbar has limited use. But Sidebar is very useful as it allows instant tag search along with nested tags.
It integrates with firefox , so that when u click on the bookmark star , it asks to save to delicious in a nice dialog box with recommended & popular tags.

Install GMarks 1.0.1

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2888

GMarks helps you sync & manage your **EDIT:firefox** bookmarks with Google Bookmarks

**EDIT:
When you want to save a bookmark
Click on the default firefox bookmark button(star) . Since you have the Official Delicious Addon installed it will ask whether you want to save to Delicious also?. Click yes and it will asks you to save to in a dialog box with recommended & popular tags.**

Now you have bookmarks in both Delicious & Firefox(Browser Bookmarks) .
Use GMarks to sync to Google Bookmarks.

How do you suppose 1 click will work? I usually tag bookmarks in delicious with the popular & recommended tags to help them sort it out

***Alternatively i use Google Toolbar. It has a button for adding Bookmarks. Position it close to the Firefox star and you won't have to move your mouse too much. It's not 1 click though***

Comment: I've used the Delicious addon for years now.  Are you saying I can use GMarks to sync my Delicious bookmarks to my Google bookmarks?

Comment: In response to your edit - That is getting closer, I think - I have never clicked the start to save a bookmark, I always right click and "Bookmark this page in Delicious", and tag it properly before saving.

By 1-click, I didn't mean click once and everything is saved.  I meant I do not want to activate the delicious addon and do tagging and save that bookmark, then activate the GMarks addon and do tagging and save that bookmark - that would be duplicated work.  If I can use the star as you say, I think that may work - I'll have to test it out.

Comment: I did as you suggested - I have it setup so I can save a bookmark to Delicious and Firefox at the same time - but somehow I can't get GMarks to notice the new Firefox bookmark and sync it to my Google Bookmarks... I looked in the GMarks options and didn't see anything about keeping them in sync.  I can use the GMarks "Save bookmark" feature and that will create a bookmark and sync it to Google, but then it skips out the save to Delicious...  Any ideas?

Comment: what about google toolbar? its more effective when saving bookmarks to google.i think u should try that 

About Gmarks i will have to try it

Comment: Gmarks is not letting me sync,only add the bookmarks :|
       
Google Toolbar is a good option i used it for a while now. if u dont mind it eating up your space.        tip: combine both google toolbar & firefox default bookmark toolbar into one by dragging

Comment: I posted a summary to my original question.  Thanks for the help, Rishi!

Comment: I've been playing with the Google toolbar along with the Delicious addon.  I can add a bookmark to FireFox and Delicious by clicking the star, but Google toolbar still won't sync.  I can use the toolbar to "Import Firefox Bookmarks", and that will pick up any new bookmarks since last import, but I can't seem to get it to sync automatically.  Maybe that can be a feature request to Google :)